# Curve function problem in discontinous point

Tags: r

I want to draw function g on interval [-1,1], where g is a function that satisfies :

for x<0 g(x)=x^2+1

otherwise g(x)=-4x-4

So I defined a function(g) :

```
g=function(x) ifelse(x<0, x^2+1, -4*x-4)
```

When I use the function `graph(g,-1,1)`, I get a graph of this function but  also a vertical line in discontinuous point (x=0).

My question is :

> Why do I get this line and how can I get rid of it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. From what package is `graph` function or please give it's implementation

Comment: My mistake IT should be curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical line jump is caused by 0, when *x == 0* you get -4. Solution could be to return `NA` when `x == 0`.

Original code:

```
g <- function(x) ifelse(x<0, x^2+1, -4*x-4)
curve(g, -1, 1, main = "Original")
```

Remove 0 (return NA):

```
g_no0 <- function(x) ifelse(x == 0, NA, ifelse(x<0, x^2+1, -4*x-4))
curve(g_no0, -1, 1, main = "No 0")
```

[image]